# Como criar links ancora e escurecer todo o resto do conteúdo da página menos a secção destinada?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, link

Quero fazer o seguinte:

```
<div id="ponto0"><a href="#ponto1"> Link </a></div>

<div id="ponto1"> 
    conteudo 
</div>
```

Ao clicar no link `href="#ponto1"` a pessoa será direccionada para o `id="ponto1"`, so que ao "saltar" para essa secção, eu quero escurecer todo o conteúdo da página exceto o `id="ponto1"` de maneira a que este fique em destaque, como no exemplo da imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estes links são chamados de - **Links Ancora**

Para criar links **ancora** para que seja possível um usuário "saltar" para uma secção especifica de uma página, utiliza `id`'s nessas secções, como por exemplo:

```
<a href="meudominio.com/sobre#linkAncora">Ir para secção sobre</a>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="linkAncora">O link acima irá ser linkado a esta secção, no qual o ID é - "linkAncora" como referido na sua Hiperligação</div>
</div>
```

Eis um exemplo abaixo:

```css
.area {height:100vh;}
#cabecalho {background-color: cadetblue;}
#conteudo {background-color: burlywood;}
#sobre {background-color: yellowgreen; font-size:45px;}
```

```html
<button><a href="#sobre">IR PARA SECÇÃO SOBRE</a></button>

<section id="cabecalho" class="area"></section>
<section id="conteudo" class="area"></section>
<section id="sobre" class="area">Sobre mim...</section>
```

### Como escurecer todo o conteúdo da página menos a secção desejada?

> Para criar esse efeito de deixar todo o conteúdo escurecido menos a secção desejada para a
>   qual iremos "saltar", será algo  como neste exemplo no
>   jsFiddle ► **http://jsfiddle.net/64n7cgqx/**

```js
$('.exposto').click(function(e){
    $(this).css('z-index','99999');
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
});

$('#overlay').click(function(e){
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $('.exposto').css('z-index','1');
    });
});
```

```css
.example {     
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    margin:5px; padding:20px;
    width:100px; height:100px;
}
.exposto {position:relative;}

#overlay {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display:none;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:99998;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="example exposto">Conteúdo aquit</div>
<textarea class="exposto">Conteúdo aqui</textarea><br />
<input type="text" class="exposto" value="Conteúdo aqui" /><br />
<div class="example exposto">Conteúdo aquit</div><br /><br />
<textarea class="exposto">Conteúdo aqui</textarea>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta funcionou certinho aqui

Comment: fico contente por ter ajudado @diogoDsa . Boa continuação de programação :)

Answer (score 0):

Só utilizando HTML e CSS podes fazer algo do género com classes:

```
.pontos{
   background-color:#000000;
}

.pontos: hover{
   background-color:#999999;
}
```